# Getting list of users in Google Admin SDK

Tags: oauth, google-admin-sdk

I have OAuth login in my app. After that I have access_token.

I check token in google token info service:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=<access_token>
```

And It returns:

```
{
"issued_to": "554651647288-tquejcu6mctplq4kin5dd9r81mtkg3vv.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"audience": "554651647288-tquejcu6mctplq4kin5dd9r81mtkg3vv.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
"expires_in": 3299,
"access_type": "online"
}
```

As you can see I have admin user directory permission.

Then I send GET request for getting information about user

```
curl -X GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/test_user@test.com?access_token=<access_token>
```

And google returned me right user information. After that I decided to get list of users.

```
curl -X GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&access_token=<access_token>
```

And google returned me:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

But I don't understand why google returned me so error.

Could you please help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions here.

1.This is the simple one. Put the URL params in quotes. This should do the trick - (fake access token used)

`curl "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&access_token=asdf.AHEasdfyIc9vuPQ_BGONpzEJkasdfWYXGujPw5iPI"`

You don't need to pass in `-X GET` as that is the default.

2.In general it is bad practice to send the `access_token` in the URL as this URL may get logged somewhere along the way for innocuous reasons. You can also do this through HTTP Header of Authorization -

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer asdf.AHEasdfyIc9vuPQ_BGONpzEJkasdfWYXGujPw5iPI" https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer`

Comment: I am getting exception message at User synchronization process "Exception message : Could not fetch URL: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&maxResults=100&pageToken=<TOKEN>"